# jquery comparing 2 variables gives unexpected result

Tags: jquery, variables

I am so much confused about a silly if condition which returns an unexpected result, I am just not able to figure out what is the problem in my code.
Here is my simple code

```
$('.for_next_link').click(function() {

    var next = $('.for_next_value_pagination').val();
    var limit = "<?php echo $max; ?>";

    alert(next); // value is 5
    alert(limit); // value is 10

    if (next >= limit) // this condition is always true
    {
        alert('im in if cond.');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // do something else;
    }
});​
```

I am comparing 2 variables "next" and "limit" which have value 5 and 10 respectively but to surprise the the if condition is always true. 
Can you please tell me why this is happening and what is the solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of limit you tried with another variable

Answer (score 1):

You are doing string comparison,
console from firebug,

```
>>> "5">"10"
true

>>> 5>10
false

>>> "5">10
false

>>> 5>"10"
false
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are comparing strings:

```
"5" >= "10" is true
```

Force the cast on one of them

```
if(next*1 >= limit*1) is false
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two string values, rather than two numbers. Try this instead:

```
if(Number(next) >= Number(limit)){
```

Because the character "5" has a higher ASCII value than "1" (the first character of "10") then "5" is regarded as being greater than "10"

Answer (score 0):

You are actually comparing `"5"` (a string) and `"10"` (also a string); `"5" > "10"` is `true` since, alphabetically, `5` comes after `1`.

Instead, compare them numerically:

```
if(parseInt(next, 10) >= parseInt(limit, 10))
```

(You may want to parse them at the same time you initialize the variable, like below)

```
var next = parseInt($('.for_next_value_pagination').val(), 10);
var limit = parseInt("<?php echo $max; ?>", 10);
```